# Callback violates Inversion of Control

Tags: ios, swift, callback, inversion-of-control, combine

If I correctly understand about IOC, it means that any framework or module you are configuring to drive your functionality should be able to drive your code whenever the need arises (Ref: [Martin Flower IOC Blog](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html)). This means that control is framework driven.

I was going through a wonderful blog [Future and Promises in Combine](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/asynchronous-programming-with-future-and-promise-in-swift-with-combine-framework/). The blog in the very beginning says that handling of asynchronous behaviour by callbacks or closures violate IOC. I kind of disagree with the statement but just want to clarify my understandings.

Scenario:

I created a `TestFramework` which handles some functionality for the framework user.

```
public class TestFramework {

    typealias UpdatedFrameworkData = (FrameworkData?) -> Void

    var giveUpdatedValues: (() -> UpdatedFrameworkData)?

    init() { }

    private func someAction() {
        var updatedValuesCallback = giveUpdatedValues?()
        updatedValuesCallback = { [weak self] updatedFrameworkData in
            // Perform some action

        }
    }
}
```

Now I have a class which uses this framework

```
class FrameworkUser {
    let framework: TestFramework = TestFramework()
    var updatedValuesCallback: TestFramework.UpdatedFrameworkData?

    init() {
       setupBinding()
    }

    private func setupBinding() {
        updatedValuesCallback = framework.giveUpdatedValues?()
    }

    private func getUpdatedData(completion: @escaping TestFramework.UpdatedFrameworkData) {
        // Return some data
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.updatedValuesCallback?(self.getFrameworkData())
        }
    }

    private func getFrameworkData() -> FrameworkData? {
        nil
    }
}
```

The framework sometimes could need to work on updated data rather than some stale data. If you observe my framework still can control the functionality of when to get updated data via the listener that is provided by the user. The user provides the data via an asynchronous callback to the framework.

So, in this case, am I not achieving IOC via callbacks or am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

I had made a minor mistake in the above code of setup binding. The user still calls the framework to provide updated values.

I made the below modifications to my above code to find out that yes asynchronous handling of a program by callbacks does violate the IOC principles. The `setupBinding()` method above is incorrect on how it binds to the callback of the Framework. It should have been something like this:

```
private func setupBinding() {
        framework.giveUpdatedValues = {
            return getUpdatedData() // This won't work
        }
    }
```

In order to follow IOC principles, the user should bind its code to the framework callback. The above code simply won't work because you can not simply just return an escaping closure from a function and this closure will be executed in some timeline later.

Comment: I think the second link is saying that _asynchronous operations implemented with callback closures_ (aka completion handlers) violate IoC, not closures per se.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks to pointing that out. Edited the question with proper examples

Answer (score 1):

A closure and a protocol are semantically identical even if they are syntactically different. If closures violate IOC then so do protocols. Since the classic example of IOC uses a protocol, that means that closures, being semantically the same don't violate it.

To show that they are the same:

```
protocol FrameworkDelegate { 
    func myFunc(data: Int)
}

class Framework {
    weak var delegate: FrameworkDelegate?

    func example() {
        delegate?.myFunc(5)
}
```

vs

```
class Framework {
    var delegate: ((Int) -> Void)?

    func example() {
        delegate(5)
    }
}
```

The only difference between the two code samples above is what object ensures that the `delegate` doesn't deinit. In both cases, the user of `Framework` defines *what* happens while the framework type determines when the "delegate method" will be called.

Comment: As @sweeper pointed in one of the comments, the author in the blog speaks about asynchronous programming using callbacks. In the code that I have mentioned in the question, you can observe the callback `giveUpdatedValues: (() -> UpdatedFrameworkData)?` of future returns a callback to the framework which provides the updated data. This callback is called by an asynchronous process from users side. I think the author sees the calling of `updatedValuesCallback ()` from the users' side to be violating IOC because again the user is calling the framework when data is available. Please CMIIW.

Comment: Interestingly, in this talk (https://frontendmasters.com/courses/rethinking-async-js/callback-problems-inversion-of-control/) the speaker asserts that async callbacks _do_ invert control and that's what's wrong with them! He explains why they invert control whereas the article you cite just makes a claim without any explanation at all.

Comment: Also the Martin Fowler article uses callbacks to show an inversion of control. Sure he does it in the context of a UI engine, but if Tk was sending the request over a network and displaying the input window on an entirely different computer, would it then mean that IOT is suddenly violated with the same code? I think not.